# How to add animation when data is changes in angular?I want to add animation on left and right button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

when I click on right and left button then data should come with animation but it didn't work for me

I added some void animation in angular and put a trigger on my HTML element animation did work when the page is refresh but it didn't work when I click on right or left button

```
animations:[
trigger('divstate',[
  state('in',style({
    opacity:1,
    transform:'translateX(0)'
  })),
  transition('void => *',[
    style({
      opacity:0,
      transform:'translateX(-100px)'
    }),
    animate(300)
  ]),
]),
```

]

```
<div class="box-2" [@divstate]>
  <div class="left-arrow">
    <a class="cursor_pointer" (click)="previousData()">
      <img src="assets/left_arrow.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="grid-1" [@divstate]>
      <div class="item-1 font_p">
        <h3 class="color_saffron" [@divstate]>{{cardData[currentPosition].section1}}</h3>
        <br>
        <p [@divstate]>{{cardData[currentPosition].section1Text}}
        </p>
        <br>
        <h3 class="color_saffron" [@divstate]>{{cardData[currentPosition].section2}}</h3><br>
        <p [@divstate]>{{cardData[currentPosition].section2Text}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-2" [@divstate]>
        <img src="{{cardData[currentPosition].image1}}" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="grid-2" [@divstate]>
      <div class="item-2">
        <img src="{{cardData[currentPosition].image2}}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item-1 font_p" [@divstate]>
        <h3 class="color_saffron">{{cardData[currentPosition].section3}}</h3>
        <br>
        <p>{{cardData[currentPosition].section3Text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-arrow">
    <a class="cursor_pointer" (click)="onAnimate()" (click)="nextData()">
      <img src="assets/right_arrow.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

whenever I click on the left or right button then data should come with animation, animation did work when the page is refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a running simple example for you here:

[Angular Animation Left | Right Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyqzfd)

Click onto the **Animate Left** | **Animate Right** | **Animate Neutral** `div` to move the blue box

Comment: Glad that i could help :)